# MySQL updates all rows when the column name is only specified in the where clause

Tags: php, mysql

It's been a while I didn't work on mysql and I was suprised to see that the following statement is valid:

```
UPDATE table_A 
SET col_a = value
WHERE id;
```

It looks like MySQL updates all rows in the table. I have a good MSSQL background and I am trying to understand why this valid in MySql?

Also, I ran a query  with a similar  where clause on a varchar column:

```
SELECT distinct description
FROM table_A 
where NOT description;
```

I tought it will return only null or empty values. Instead, it returns lots of rows with non-null values.

Any ideas why?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WHERE x` will match any rows for which `x` evaluates to a truthy value. Since `BOOLEAN` is actually a number type `TINYINT(1)`, this works by converting to a number and then comparing to zero - any nonzero number is truthy. (`NULL` is falsy.)

If you write `WHERE id = 123`, then only for the row where `id` is `123`, the expression `id = 123` will evaluate to `TRUE` (which is the same as `1`) and it will match, otherwise it will evaluate to `FALSE` (`0`).

But if you write `WHERE id`, the requirement is that `id` evaluates to a truthy value. If `id` is a number, only IDs `0` and `NULL` will be falsy.

However, in case of `description`, you have a string. And the string is first converted to a number. The reason you got many results there is that any string that starts with a number (that is nonzero) is matching, such as `01234hello` (which converts to 1234, which is nonzero). Check what `CONVERT(description, SIGNED)` gives - if it is nonzero, then it matches.

<sub>This is why, when building `AND` or `OR` queries in code, you can avoid handling the case of zero conditions specially by starting with `TRUE` or `1` (in the `AND` case) or `FALSE` or `0` (in the `OR` case), since `WHERE TRUE`/`WHERE 1` is valid (matches everything), as is `WHERE FALSE`/`WHERE 0` (matches nothing). So you build a query by starting with `WHERE 1` and adding to it: `WHERE 1`, `WHERE 1 AND id = 123`, `WHERE 1 AND id = 123 AND type = 'xy'`, etc.</sub>